# Check Box makes Label Visible

Tags: ms-access

I have three Combo Boxes - When they are selected i would like it to check the tick box.

if the check box is ticked the Text box will then become Enabled, i currently have it set as disabled.

my question is how would i set the check box to be true when the three Combos are selected.

and how would i make it so that when the tick box is true it will enable the tex box

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When all 3 combo boxes are set it will enable the checkbox. Once the value for any combo box is updated it calls a common function which checks whether all combo boxes have a value assigned and accordingly set the checkbox.

```
Private Sub cmbClientContact_AfterUpdate()
   Call SetCheckBox
End Sub

Private Sub cmbClientName_AfterUpdate()
    Call SetCheckBox
End Sub

Private Sub cmbProjectManager_AfterUpdate()
    Call SetCheckBox
End Sub

Private Sub SetCheckBox()
     If Nz(Me.cmbClientContact, "") <> "" And Nz(Me.cmbClientName, "") <> "" And Nz(Me.cmbProjectManager, "") <> "" Then
        Me.Check25 = True
        Me.Text27.Enabled = True
     Else
        Me.Check25 = False
     End If
End Sub
```

---

Enable/disable textbox basis value of the checkbox

```
Private Sub Check25_AfterUpdate()
    If Nz(Me.Check25, False) Then
        Me.Text27.Enabled = True
    Else
        Me.Text27.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you have been a massive help to me recently! all your solutions have proven to work and you have provided simple and easy to understand fixes. Thankyou

Comment: On issue, the value are selected and tick box ticks (which works!) the Text box does not become automatically enabled. i have to tick it manually for it to enable.

Comment: Ok try this  `Private Sub SetCheckBox()
     If Nz(Me.cmbClientContact, "") <> "" And Nz(Me.cmbClientName, "") <> "" And Nz(Me.cmbProjectManager, "") <> "" Then
        Me.Check25 = True
 Check25_AfterUpdate
     Else
        Me.Check25 = False
     End If
End Sub`

Comment: The check_afterupdate comes up with a compile error (expected end statement  Private Sub SetCheckBox()
If Nz(Me.cmbClientContact, "") <> "" And Nz(Me.cmbClientName, "") <> "" And Nz(Me.cmbProjectManager, "") <> "" Then
Me.Check25 = True
Check_AfterUpdate Else
Me.Check25 = False
End If
End Sub

Comment: Yes! that seems to work! thankyou again santosh you've been a massive help to me!

Answer (score 3):

I would reccomend using the `AfterUpdate` event of all 3 combo boxes. Since the code is going to be the same (you're checking if all 3 combo boxes have a value), you can create one function to handle the check, and set that function to the `AfterUpdate` event of all 3 combo boxes when the form loads.

The function to update the controls (both the text box and check box) would be something like this:

```
  Private Function UpdateControls()
     Me.Text1.Enabled = Not (IsNull(Me.Combo1) Or IsNull(Me.Combo2) Or IsNull(Me.Combo3))
     Me.Check1.Value = Not (IsNull(Me.Combo1) Or IsNull(Me.Combo2) Or IsNull(Me.Combo3))
  End Function
```

You can call this function when the form initially loads, so the checkbox will be unchecked and the textbox will be disabled:

```
  Private Sub Form_Load()       
     ' update controls initially when the form loads
     UpdateControls
  End Sub
```

To make sure the same update happens whenever one of the combo box's values are updated, you can set each combobox's `AfterUpdate` event to the same function, like this:

```
  Private Sub Form_Load()
     ' set each combo box's AfterUpdate event to run the check
     Me.Combo1.AfterUpdate = "=UpdateControls()"
     Me.Combo2.AfterUpdate = "=UpdateControls()"
     Me.Combo3.AfterUpdate = "=UpdateControls()"
  End Sub
```

So your final code might be something like this:

```
  Private Sub Form_Load()
     ' set each combo box's AfterUpdate event to run the check
     Me.Combo1.AfterUpdate = "=UpdateControls()"
     Me.Combo2.AfterUpdate = "=UpdateControls()"
     Me.Combo3.AfterUpdate = "=UpdateControls()"

     ' update controls initially when the form loads
     UpdateControls
  End Sub

  Private Function UpdateControls()
     Me.Text1.Enabled = Not (IsNull(Me.Combo1) Or IsNull(Me.Combo2) Or IsNull(Me.Combo3))
     Me.Check1.Value = Not (IsNull(Me.Combo1) Or IsNull(Me.Combo2) Or IsNull(Me.Combo3))
  End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more specifics about the name schemas of your objects, this is my semi-vague answer:

One option (of many) is to use an `On Click` event procedure with the following:

```
If Not IsNull(Me.Combo1) _
And Not IsNull(Me.Combo2) _
And Not IsNull(Me.Combo3) Then
    Me.Check1 = True
    Me.Text1.Enabled = True
Else
    Me.Check1 = False
    Me.Text1.Enabled = False
End If
```

This assumes that the checkbox is named `Check1` and the textbox is named `Text1` and the comboboxes are `Combo1`, `Combo2`, and `Combo3`

It is a little confusing whether you meant `Enabled` or `Visible`, but if you meant `Visible`, just change the lines that say `.Enabled` to `.Visible`